# If $A$ is a $12 \times 12$ real matrix such that $A^{17}=I$ , is $A$ diagonalizable ? Are all eigenvalues of $A$ real ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

If $A$ is a $12 \times 12$ real matrix such that $A^{17}=I$ , is $A$ diagonalizable ? Are all eigenvalues of $A$ real ?

Comment: @supinf : Nothing much comes to mind except that all eigenvalues should satisfy $\lambda ^ {17} =1$

Comment: @Chilango  How does it help ?

Comment: do you know that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @Chilango, don't you mean $A^{18} - A = A^{17}(A - 1) - 0$?

Comment: @Vincent: I meant to write the matrix form of the characteristic polynomial so that the OP could use the fact that the minimal poly divides it and so conclude that A is not diagonalizable unless it is the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides 
$$x^{17} - 1 = \left(x - 1\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{16} x^i \right).$$
Since $x^{17} - 1$ has only one real root $x = 1$, the factorization over $\mathbb{R}$ of $x^{17} - 1$ is of the form $(x - 1)p_1(x) \ldots p_8(x)$ where $p_i$ are quadratics without real roots.

Since a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits into linear factors, we see that a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ that satisfies $A^{17} = I$ will be diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x - 1)$ which means that $A = I_n$. If $A \neq I_n$, then $A$ will have at least two conjugate non-real complex eigenvalues.

Comment: You mean the only way that $A$ will be diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ is if $A = I$.  Any such $A$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Of course. I've added a clarification, thanks.

Comment: Nice answer. ${}{}$

Comment: Nice answer, but not to the stated question, -1. It asks (both in title and body) "is $A$ diagonalizable" rather than give "$A$ is diagonalizable" as hypothesis.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I thought it was clear from what I wrote that the answer is "No, $A$ will be diagonalizable if and only if $A = I$". I've rephrased my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

No and no (that is: not necessarily diagonalisable over $\def\R{\Bbb R}\R$, and its complex eigenvalues need not be real).

Write $\R^{12}\simeq\R^2\oplus\R^{10}$, let the matrix act as a rotation by $2\pi/17$ on the $\R^2$ component and as the identity on the $\R^{10}$ component.